# What does "rejected" mean in the migrated page?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, statistics

Looking at the statistics page for the migrated questions, I read the word *rejected*. Does that mean it is possible to reject a migration before it is done, or it is referring to the questions that have been migrated, and then closed?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Migrated and then subsequently closed or deleted. It lets us see if there are any giant problems (for example, if a site migrations 30 questions and 90% get closed, we need to have a talk with them about when migrations to us are ok). But it doesn't really affect us since we don't get so many migrations.

Comment: I was hoping that the famous "approve before migrating" was already implemented. `:-)`